# How big a slave rebellion could one thousand soldiers realistically stop in an urban setting?

Tags: warfare, slavery

It is a bronze age setting, and the one thousand soldiers are well-equipped, well-trained, battle-hardened. They are facing a rebellion made up of X slaves. The slaves are equipped with basic tools and aren't trained warriors. The rebellion takes place in a city.

So the question is : How big is X, realistically?

Comment: "well-equipped" can you give a time period or setting? because this can mean anything from spears and shields to Power armor exo-skeletons and laser mini guns :|

Comment: @A.bakker It's a bronze age setting; I was imagining them having spears and somthing like dendra panoplies.

Comment: purerly opinion based question - it depend on time it take. There is a game where you can put X amount of set soldeirs agaisnt Y anything (with wild boars included). During Third Servile War around 70 gladiators defended Roman forces in Capua. There is also diffrence beetwen Memphis and Mycanos.

Comment: Much more info is needed, too many variables to consider. As almost always in warfare, tactics is going to be decisive. Splitting your 1000 soldiers into a hundred platoons and scatter them over the whole city would have different effects than going in force to protect the City Hall, for example. How big is the city? The slaves control any checkpoints, barricades? What is the rest of the population doing? Who are they supporting, the slaves or the army?

Comment: In all (maybe only *almost* all, but I can't think of a counter example) bronze age cities the armed adult free men would quickly overwhelm any abortive slave rebellion. Bronze age cities were not really populated by hordes of armed slaves. (And I don't exactly understand why would the slaves rebel in any bronze age city I can think of. Servitude was a normal status in life back then. Large-scale slave revolts happened very much later, in a very different socio-economic context. Are you confusing the bronze age with [Roman-era Sicily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Servile_War)?)

Comment: (Addendum: There were not all that many slaves in bronze age citties. There were slaves, true, but they were a minority. It would be like a rebellion of the plumbers, electricians and house maids in modern New York.)

Comment: I'm inclined to say 10 to 1, but have no evidence of it!